# How to implement greater than or less than dates in php

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

i have a small confusion here . in my  project i need to display prices for rooms as per dates . for example .
from 01 oct 2017 to 31st oct 2017 price is $200.
from 01st nov to 30th nov price is $250 and so on .....

now i am trying to do it this way ....

```
     <?php 

            $currnt_time = time();
            $from_date = strtotime(2017-10-01);
            $till_date = strtotime(2017-10-31);

            if ($currnt_time >= $from_date && $currnt_time < $till_date){
                $price = $200;
            }

            ?>
          <P> Starts FROM <?php echo $price; ?> INR</P>
```

but when i run this script it says undefined variable $price . i cant understand where i am wrong ) and as i will be having many dates slots like above so what will be the best way to solve this .
Please help. Thanks !

Comment: Other than some syntax errors which I asume come from the editing of the snippet, it [should work](https://3v4l.org/jloJ2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `$` in front of the value for `$price`, and you've fogetten to add the quote before and after date strings.

```
<?php 
    $currnt_time = time();
    $from_date = strtotime('2017-10-01');
    $till_date = strtotime('2017-10-31');

    if ($currnt_time >= $from_date && $currnt_time < $till_date){
        $price = 200;
    }

    ?>
  <P> Starts FROM <?php echo $price; ?> INR</P>
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ! working .... small confusion ... which date is always  greater past or future ?

Comment: one more small question how can i dynamically put year rather than hardcoding like 2017 ....??? because in above case i need to change my code every year .. any solution please

Comment: Use php's date.  date('Y');

Comment: But if I have slot like from  2 Dec 2017 to 2 Jan 2018 then?

Comment: Whatever you have, the `strtotime()` gonna convert it to the right value. The future has greater value than the past. @kohali

Comment: Sorry again disturbing... but i think this trick wont work . for example.  slot like from 1st dec 2017 to 31st jan 2018 . in this case if suppose today is 1st of dec 2017 then as per script it will assume values like this .                               $from_date = strtotime('2017-12-01');
    $till_date = strtotime('2017-01-31');   because code is saying the year is still 2017 today. so what will be the comparison ?